# Haskell: How to safely implement max using Maybe?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to implement a recursive safe `max` function that returns `Nothing` if an empty list is provided and `Just a` in case a maximum is found.

A naive approach (that just returns zero if an empty list is provided) would look like this:

```
max' :: [Int] -> Int
max' [] = 0
max' (x:xs) | x < max' xs = max' xs
            | otherwise = x
```

Now using the Prelude Maybe data type:

```
safeMax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a
safeMax [] = Nothing
safeMax [x] = x
safeMax (x:y:xs) | x = safeMax (y:xs)
               | otherwise = Just x
```

I get the message that it cannot construct the infinite data type `a ~ Maybe a`. What is here the problem?

The full error message is this:

```
safemax.hs:33:15: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Maybe a
    • In the expression: x
      In an equation for ‘safeMax’: safeMax [x] = x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a (bound at safemax.hs:33:10)
        safeMax :: [a] -> Maybe a (bound at safemax.hs:32:1)
   |
33 | safeMax [x] = x
```

---

Solution: Use `Just x` and use `x < y`:

```
safeMax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a
safeMax [] = Nothing
safeMax [x] = Just x
safeMax (x:y:xs) | x < y = safeMax (y:xs)
               | x > y = safeMax (x:xs)
               | otherwise = Just x
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: You also modified the code in your last edit. You shouldn't do that because not my answer below makes absolutely no sense. Also, if you solved the problem, just post an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: I restored the initial version of the question, your answer now should make sense again, sorry for that.. was editing while there still were no answers.

Comment: As an aside, your naive version is also incorrect for non-empty lists containing only negative numbers.

Comment: As an aside (code golf) you can also write this as `safeMax xs = maximum (Nothing : map Just xs)` or `safeMax = foldl max Nothing . map Just`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson ...but this trick is a bit subtle; e.g. it doesn't work for `safeMin`! For reusing `maximum` it's probably clearer to just pattern match, as in `safeMax [] = Nothing; safeMax xs = Just (maximum xs)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I get your point that bringing in more machinery is actually detrimental to code readability and correctness.  Still, the obvious path forward is to keep digging our hole with even more machinery and fix this problem.  All we need is a functor version of the Down Monoid, `FDown`, where `instance (Eq (FDown f a), Ord (f (Down a)), Functor f) => Ord (FDown f a) where compare (FDown x) (FDown y) = compare (Down <$> x) (Down <$> y)`.  With that it's pretty easy to define safe min as `unFDown . foldl max (FDown Nothing) . map (FDown . Just)`.  That's production quality, that is.

Comment: @DanielWagner I dislike the pattern match as you're still directly calling a partial function, which obvs is safe here but in general creates vulnerability to refactoring. My vote is for `safeMax = maximum1 <.> nonEmpty` (only two extra packages needed since Ghc 8 got non-empty lists!)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with `x < safeMax xs`. Here you are trying to use `(<)` to compare an `a` with a `Maybe a`. You need to unwrap the return value from `safeMax xs` before doing this comparison.

Comment: I got it.. *Just* now:)

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is close. `safeMax []` isn't really a base case, since no recursive call will ever be made on a empty list (the second case `safeMax [x] = ...` ensures that). So once you know that `safeMax (y:xs)` in your third case can *only* return a `Just` value, you can safely pattern match on that.

```
safeMax (x:y:xs) = let Just y' = safeMax (y:xs)
                   in Just $ if x >= y' then x else y'
```

Now you'll realize that you unnecessarily matched the tail of the original input; you don't care about the value of `y` at all. Get rid of it, and just recurse on the tail.

```
safeMax (x:xs) = let Just y = safeMax xs
                 in Just $ if x >= y then x else y
```

Since `[]` isn't really a base case, you can define `safeMax` to use a helper function that can assume a non-empty list.

```
safeMax [] = Nothing
safeMax = Just . safeMax'
   where safeMax' [x] = Just x
         safeMax' (x:xs) = let y = safeMax' xs
                           in if x >= y then x else y
```

Of course, `safeMax'` is just `Prelude.maximum`, so you can write, as suggested by Daniel Wagner,

```
safeMax [] = Nothing
safeMax xs = Just (maximum xs)
```